# An example code for doing a loop

Tags: list-manipulation, code-request, procedural-programming

I would like a code that works for doing loops as in the toy example below. This would help me to understand how to work with loops in more general contexts as I am still a beginner in Mathematica. The example is:

Consider `list1={A,B,C,D}`, `f1[A]=f1[B]=0`, `f1[f2[C]]=0` and `f1[f2[f2[D]]]=0`, where the constraints on the functions `f1` and `f2` is that they only need to satisfy the previous properties.

(i) In the first stage of the code, we apply `f1` to each of the elements in `list1`. Given that `f1[A]=f1[B]=0`, the code should save (to print later) `A` and `B` and keep `C` and `D`, because `f1[C]` and `f1[D]` do not vanish.

(ii) In the second stage, we apply `f2` to the elements that were not zero when we applied `f1` in the first stage. So that we should have a list `{f2[C],f2[D]}`, and then apply `f1` to the elements of the latter. Given that `f1[f2[C]]=0`, the code should save `f2[C]` and keep `f2[D]` to return to the loop.

(iii) Finally, going back to stage (ii), we apply `f2` to `f2[D]` so we would be left with the list `{f2[f2[D]]}` and after applying `f1` to this list it gives zero, because `f1[f2[f2[D]]]=0`, so that we save `f2[f2[D]]` and the process would be finished in this example.

(iv) In the end, I want the code to print as a list all the elements generated in the process that when acted with `f1` give zero. The answer, in this case, would be `{A,B,f2[C],f2[f2[D]]}`. This list shouldn't count repeated elements twice.

Comment: What have you tried? Note that loops are not really idiomatic in Mathematica. See eg [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/27951). Also avoid uppercase single-character variables, as many of those have built in meaning (e.g. C, D, E, I, K, N, O ...); use lowercase variable names instead.

Comment: Consider `Select` as an example of a tool that might be helpful in your selection of elements from a list that give rise to a certain function output.

Comment: You can check out the [introductory book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor to help you get started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we define the conditions:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
list = {a, b, c, d};
f1[a] = 0;
f1[b] = 0;
f1[f2[c]] = 0;
f1[f2[f2[d]]] = 0;
```

Then we apply the 3 steps. The result is accumulated by Sow/Reap in the variable res:

```
res = Reap[
    t = If[f1[#] === 0, Sow[#]; Nothing, #] & /@ list ;
    t = If[t = f2[#]; f1[t] === 0, Sow[t]; Nothing, t] & /@ t;
    If[t = f2[#]; f1[t] === 0, Sow[t]; Nothing, t] & /@ t;
    ][[2]];
res


   (*  {{a, b, f2[c], f2[f2[d]]}} *)
```

Comment: Is there a way to change your solution such that the code works also if instead of only applying f2 two times until we found 'f1[f2[f2[d]]] = 0' it would apply any number of times? In this case it would also work if 'f1f[f2[f2[f2[d]]] ]= 0', etc

Comment: "Any number of times", that is an infinite number of times, does not seem feasible. However, for three, you would have to duplicate the second case (t= If[...)

Comment: For any finite number of times, is there another way to do this without having replicate the second case?

Comment: You could repeat the second case in a While loop until nothing is left over..